# No questions have been added to this group

Tags: 7

I am using Drupal Commons 2.10, and every time I click on the Q&A tab of a group, this message appears:

> No questions have been added to this group.

When I create a question, it states that the question has been created, but it doesn't appear under the Q&A tab.

What have I messed up?